# Ubuntu Video Library manager

Tags: linux, video, ubuntu, media-manager

I'm looking for a video library manager that works for Ubuntu 16.04. Some of the key capabilities is to be able to sort-by and manage ID3 tags and playback mp4 files within the application.

With all its faults, iTunes was good for this back when I used Windows, and Miro was a great alternative, but I've abandoned Windows and the developers have abandoned Miro.

Anyone know of anything still maintained that can do this? I didn't think it'd be so hard to find something to do this. (I've been making due with nautilus-python extensions, but it's not the most CPU-efficient way of going about it...)