# Calibre-like application for films on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, collection-manager

I'm using Calibre on Ubuntu to sort my library, and I've never seen an application so beautiful. This made me wonder - is there a similar application for films and music?

I'm looking for something that can

- Download info about my films
- Edit tags
- Rename the files according to some template
- Categorize according to director/actors/genre
- Add covers

I've heard about iTunes, but it's not supported on Ubuntu. [Same question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35981/ubuntu-video-library-manager) has been asked before, but to no avail.

Comment: I once used [Serviio media server](http://serviio.org/) for that. But it's not open, and after a 30d (?) trial half of its functions was blocked (especially the WebIF you'd use for the tasks mentioned). As I rarely need that functionality, I decided to skip it then. Might be worth a look, though – but it looks different from Calibre ;)

Comment: @Izzy  -  when I say beautiful, I mean efficient, not the visuals. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look

Comment: Efficient it is. If it recognizes a film/music, it even loads descriptions. Other than Calibre, this might take a little to configure it such, though ;) If it looks acceptable, please let me know whether I shall make it a full-fledged answer :)